# How to detect constant absolute delta in integer series?

Tags: pandas

I have integer series as follows:

```
data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]

data2 = [4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0]
```

We can see `data1` seems to be "continuous" while `data2` is not, as `data1` has a maximum constant absolute delta of 1.

How can I decide using Pandas that `data1` is "continuous", and data2 is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define continuous to mean "consecutive differences are at most 1 in absolute value". To detect this, you can use `.diff()`:

```
In [1]: series1, series2 = pd.Series(data1), pd.Series(data2)

In [2]: series1.diff().fillna(0).abs().max()
Out[2]: 1.0

In [3]: series2.diff().fillna(0).abs().max()
Out[3]: 8.0
```

So `series1.diff().fillna(0).abs().max() <= 1` will evaluate to `True`, and `series2.diff().fillna(0).abs().max() <= 1` will evaluate to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Andrey's solution but this takes advantage of pandas' rolling windows series method.

```
data1.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: abs(np.diff(x)) <= 1).all()
>>> True

data2.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: abs(np.diff(x)) <= 1).all()
>>> False
```